# git remote add web page on github

Tags: git, github-pages

I'm creating a page on github (mypage.github.io). I have selected in "setting" the option "master branch"

Your site is published at https://mypage.github.io/mypage/ (only content README).

Note: For privacy reasons, the real name is changed to "mypage"

Now, on my PC I have all the files and folders with the design of the page, to upload them to this repository

```
/mypage/
```

To upload (first time) it I use the following commands:

```
/mypage/git init
/mypage/git add .
/mypage/git commit -m "Commit"
```

The problem is with this command:

```
/mypage/git remote add origin https://github.com/mypage/mypage.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

How do I correctly execute the "git remote add" command to add the content to my web page on github?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get if you do `git remote -v`?

Comment: Oh, hold on, `git remote add` add's a new remote repo. If you want to push to this remote you want `git push`. You only need to add the remote once then push to it multiple times. read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: origin https://github.com/mypage/mypage (fetch)
origin https://github.com/mypage/mypage (push)

Comment: Yeah, your remotes are already set up. You don't need to run `git remote add`. I'm pretty sure you want `git push`

Comment: git push -f origin master or only git push?

Comment: try with only `git push`

Comment: I doubt you need to force it. `git push` should be fine.

Comment: thanks!. If you wish, put your answer separately, to select it as correct

Comment: Maybe read through a [git tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing) to understand better whats going on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your getting pushing to a remote repo and setting up a remote repo on your local repo mixed up.

```
git remote add
```

Sets up a new remote source in your local repo. It does not send anything to this repo. It essentially says, when I `push` (or `fetch`) this is where I want it to go.

```
git push
```

Pushes your local repo changes to the remote setup above. i.e. it sends you local changes to the remote repo.